# Generating HTML documents in PHP

Tags: php, html, mailchimp

So what im trying, is speed up the process of sending mails using Mailchimp.
I want to do this by simply changing the data from my mailing-template.
My company normally did this by hand but it takes way to much time.
So first of i tried simply changing my mailing-template using PHP.
The thing is, Mailchimp can only read the HTML documents and completely ignores the PHP.
I tried .htaccess to use PHP in my HTMLfile but Mailchimp also wont read the .htaccess file.

Problem: I can only load in HTML files and Mailchimp can only read HTML code.

My question: Can i generate HTML documents using PHP?

Let me try to explane my situation better.
Lets say this is my template,
*mailing-template.html*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mailing-Template</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="productBox">
                <h1 id="productName">Product Name</h1>
                <p id="productInfo">product info</p>
            </div>
        </body>         
</html>
```

So for my mailing i need my product name and product information to change per product.
As i mentioned i can not use anything else than html since i want to import my template to Mailchimp.

What i need to do is change some product info in my mailing-template.html without needing any other languages to support it.
The only thing i can think of is generating my mailing-template using another coding language and than use the generated file as my template.

Im not even sure if thats possible or if there's a much better way i'm missing. Im pretty new to all this, so thats why im asking for help.

Appreciate your time. :)

Comment: Yes you can create HTML file from PHP. Generate the markup in a variable then use `file_put_contents` to make your file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can generate html documents using php.

```
<?php
  //Simply store all the html code in a variable as shown below,
  $pagehtml = "your html will go here";
?>
```

You can pass this varibale to next page using sessions or you can simply create a page with .php extension and echo the variable (e.g. $pagehtml) content to your desired location.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PHP can do this, quick example

```
//create html file for writing
$file = fopen("file.html", "a+") or  die ( "File creation failed".error_get_last() );

//add your content to $content variable
$content='<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mailing-Template</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="productBox">
                <h1 id="productName">Product Name</h1>
                <p id="productInfo">product info</p>
            </div>
        </body>         
</html>';

//write the content to the file
fwrite($file, $content);

//close the completed file
fclose($file);
```

Comment: where is the part where dinamically OP can change the Product Name and Product info?

Comment: The question was "Can i generate HTML documents using PHP?".

Comment: No the question is: _"I want to do this by simply changing the data from my mailing-template. My company normally did this by hand but it takes way to much time"_

Comment: @DjHexy my bad, should've made my question more clear. You actually did answer the question i asked.

Comment: @LelioFaieta is right tho, my actual question was: "I want to do this by simply changing the data from my mailing-template. My company normally did this by hand but it takes way to much time".

Comment: So the thing is thanks to lelio (and some more nice people) i can now import the HTML file created in an PHP file to Mailchimp. But i still need to find a way to change my product name and info before importing it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help!
I know generate a HTMLfile where i can change my data by just throwing a variable in the content.

```
//create html file for writing
        $file = fopen("file.html", "a+") or  die ( "File creation failed".error_get_last() );

//set product name
$productName = "Product Name";

        //add content to $content variable
        $content='
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Mailing-Template</title>
            </head>
                <body>
                    <div id="productBox">
                        <h1 id="productName">' . $productName . '</h1>
                        <p id="productInfo">product info</p>
                    </div>
                </body>         
        </html>';

        //write the content to the file
        fwrite($file, $content);

        //close the completed file
        fclose($file);
```

Appreciate the help :)